# PHP split array at between values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, slice

I have an array with data set out as follows

```
[0] =>"npage:new",
[1] =>"data:data",
[2] =>"data:data",
[3] =>"npage:new",
[4] =>"data:data",
[5] =>"data:data",
[6] =>"data:data",
[7] =>"npage:new",
[8] =>"data:data",
[9] =>"data:data",
```

Im trying to rearrange the array so that at each "npage:new"  it creates another index for the data between it and the next  "npage:new". until the last set which does not have  "npage:new" but will still need an index.
Example:

```
[0] =>    
     "data:data",
     "data:data",
[1] =>
     "data:data",
     "data:data",
     "data:data",
[2] =>
     "data:data",
     "data:data",
```

I have the following, but It returns a blank array  & I think I'm over complicating things.

```
    $source[] = the array
    $destination =  array();
$startval = "new";
$found = 0;
$starindex = 0;

foreach ($source as $index => $value){
if ($value === $startval) {
$found = $value;
$startindex = $index;
} 
    elseif ( $value === $found) {
$destination[] = array_slice($source, $startindex, $index - $startindex + 1);
$found = 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://codepad.org/QCWTAhnq

```
<?php
$source = array("npage:new", "data:data", "data:data", "npage:new", "data:data", "data:data", "data:data", "data:data", "npage:new", "data:data", "npage:new", "data:data", "data:data");
$final =  array();
$newpage = "npage:new";

$temp = array();

foreach ($source as $index => $value) {
    if ($value == $newpage) {
        if(!empty($temp)) {
            $final[] = $temp;
            $temp = array();
        }
    } 
    else {
        $temp[] = $value;
    }
}

if(!empty($temp))
   $final[] = $temp;

print_r($final);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I don't write php but try something like this:

```
$source[] = the array
$destination =  array();
$startval = "new";
$ix = -1;

foreach ($source as $index => $value) {
    if ($value === $startval) {
        $ix++;
        $dest[$ix] = array();
    } 
    else {
        array_push($dest[$ix], $index.":".$value;
    }
}
```